# XE6 Datasnap wizard is not available

Tags: database, delphi, wizard, datasnap, delphi-xe6

I have XE6 Professional installed which is fully licensed.

I am trying to create a DataSnap server using the wizard as shown in this link http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/DataSnap_Server_Wizard

File > New > Other > Delphi Projects > DataSnap Server > DataSnap Server

I have no DataSnap Server option available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever have had an eye on the [feature matrix](http://www.embarcadero.com/de/products/rad-studio/rad-studio-feature-matrix.pdf). That should answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*DataSnap* is just not part of the *Professional* edition of Delphi XE6.

As stated by the [Delphi Product Editions page](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/product-editions), you have to upgrade to the *Entreprise* edition.

You have alternative around, e.g.

- [RemObjects DataAbstract](http://www.remobjects.com/da) which allows remote access to your database;
- [TMS Business Subscription](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/bipack.asp) with TMS RemoteDB / Sparckle / Aurelius;
- Our Open Source [mORMot framework](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SQLite3+Framework) which works fine with Delphi XE6 professional.

Note that you have optimized database access classes in our *mORMot* framework: it is able to connect to *SQLite3, Oracle, Jet/MSAccess, MS SQL, Firebird, DB2, PostgreSQL, MySQL* and *NexusDB* (via OleDB, ODBC or via [ZDBC](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/02/12/Introducing-ZEOS%2C-UniDAC%2C-NexusDB%2C-BDE%2C-any-TDataset-to-SynDB-and-mORMot-s-ORM)), without the need of purchasing the *FireDAC* add-on from Embarcadero.

Comment: i searhed mORMot which is better than the DataSnap, thanks for helping